# how to fix whitespaces in a website when the window gets smaller

Tags: html, css

When the window gets smaller words jump to another line and white-space between the words become bigger; incidentally the website is in Arabic not in English

I tried to reduce the width of the div that contains them and nothing changed; but I don't know if the problem is the language.

```css
.content {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  /*text-align: justify;*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>
    <h1>أهلا بك في SyTech أول موقع خاص في محافظة طرطوس!</h1>
  </p>
  <p>
    <h2> إن موقعنا يساعد في زيادة حركة التجارة الإلكترونية بهدف تطوير مجال التكنولوجيا في وطننا الحبيب سوريا.<br>و هذا يعني أنه بإمكانك استخدام الموقع لعرض البضائع التي تريد بيعها أو تصفح البضائع المنشورة من قبل أشخاص آخرين!</h2>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <p>إن المبرمج الوحيد الذي عمل على هذا الموقع هو تيم زغيبة</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have used, text-align:justify?

Comment: Can you post enough of your code (the HTML and CSS as a [mcve], ideally as a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) so that we can recreate your problem. It doesn't matter that the site content is in Arabic, so long as we can read and understand the HTML and its associated elements' `id` and `class` attributes.

Comment: @Salman yes i did

Comment: @Salman i commented "text-align: justify" out and it worked but the problem is the text doesnt look good

Comment: @DavidThomas is Those ok?? open the console in the browser if you are on chrome you can toggle device toolbar, to see the problem on smaller screen

Comment: Code relevant to the question should not be posted in comments, since it's near impossible to read anything but a small excerpt in comment. This time I've added the code to your question as a runnable snippet, as I requested. But yes, the code helps (I hope), thank you! :)